# How to write insert sql with where statement?

Tags: c#, sql, insert, where-clause

The problem is why can't i get the insert values into my database. ( i am not sure the "where statement")

Target: i want to save the random number in the database , which is used for the email authentication number.

---

```
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        connection.ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb";

        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int number = rnd.Next(1000, 5000);

        command.CommandText = "insert into Registration ([Authentication]) values (@number) where [Email] = '"+ TextBox1.Text +"';";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", number);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("sucessfull");
```

Comment: INSERT means ADDING a new record. WHERE is used when you want to change an existing record. If this is the case then you should use an UPDATE statement instead

Comment: looks like you want to use update instead of insert

Comment: my target is that if the email address is matched in my database , and then it will add a random number in the record.

Comment: command.CommandText = "update Registration set ([Authentication]) values (@number) where [Email] = '"+ TextBox1.Text +"';";                                                            is there any problem?? i can't make it work

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3):

A part from the simple error of using an INSERT query when you need an UPDATE query, there are a couple of things to change in your code to make it follow best practices.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int number = rnd.Next(1000, 5000);

string cmdText = @"UPDATE Registration 
                   SET [Authentication] = @number
                   WHERE [Email] = @email";
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(....connectionstring ....))
using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@number", OleDbType.Integer).Value = number;
    command.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    int rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(rowsUpdated > 0)
        MessageBox.Show("sucessfull");
    else        
        MessageBox.Show("email not found");
}
```

First, every disposable object (like connections and commands) should be enclosed in an [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure the proper closing and disposing also in case of exceptions. Second, every command text used to interact with your database should always be written using parameters and not with a string concatenation. This is the correct way to pass values to your database and helps to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems. (not to mention a better understandability of your query text).
Finally, it is better to avoid AddWithValue because it has serious drawbacks as you can read from this article: [Can we stop to use AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)